# HTML5 validation message is way too far down

Tags: html, validation

```
 <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label text-left "})
        <div class="">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new {htmlAttributes = new {id = "title", @class = "form-control checkIfFilled", placeholder = "F.eks. Front-end udvikler", required = "required"}}) 
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

why is it so far below? it looks like it went under the "By" field.

here is the checkIfFilled() function

```
function checkIfFilled() {
        var allGood = [];

        $('.checkIfFilled').each(function (i, obj) {
            if ($(obj).val() == null || $(obj).val() == "") {
                allGood.push(false);
            }
            else {
                allGood.push(true);

            }
        });
        if(allGood.includes(false)){
            $('.checkFilled').prop("disabled", true);

        }
        else if ($('.panel-body').html() != null && $('.panel-body').html() != "<p><br></p>")
        {
            $('.checkFilled').prop("disabled", false);

        }
}
```

However, removing it will still not affect the message.

Comment: Is there a reason why your `div` doesn't have a `class`?  Shouldn't that be a `col-*-*`?

Comment: not at the moment, my colleague left it there, but deleting it doesn't affect the message position. It is still way down.

Comment: What if you did `<div class="col-md-10">`?

Comment: doesn't affect the message

Comment: what is `checkIfFilled`?

Comment: a function I made, added it into the original post, doesn't affect the message position

Comment: Have you checked `margin` / `padding`? and other styles

Comment: yes, I didn't add anything out of the ordinary

Comment: Duplicate of [Chrome validation message bubble in the wrong position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40901507/chrome-validation-bubbles-in-wrong-position) but I can't close it because the target doesn't yet have an upvoted/accepted answer. :-(