# Chrome validation message bubble in the wrong position

Tags: html, google-chrome, validation

So I've written a small demo with highlights the problem:

```html
<form>
  <label>Test field</label>
  <input type="text" required="required" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

If the code is run on Firefox or Edge, the validation bubble occurs in the correct position:

[image: Firefox]

[image: Edge]

But Chrome does this:

[image: Chrome]

How can I make sure the validation bubble is in the correct location? Do I need to do something additional in Chrome?

I've tested this on two separate PCs to replicate the issue, I'm using version 54.0.2840.99 m (64-bit).

Comment: that's strange. I tried also and it displays on the wrong position. I think it's an issue on chrome

Answer (score 0):

This was a Chrome bug specific to that version; it has since been fixed in subsequent major versions.